# Properly Venting a Dryer

Tags: vent, attic, dryer

[image: Dryer is currently vented directly into the attic]

**BACKGROUND INFO:** 
We have an upstairs laundry room with the dryer vented directly into the attic space! House was built in '84, maybe had three previous owners before us. Not sure what the code was back then, but what you see in the picture was probably NEVER up to code to begin with!

**QUESTIONS:**

1. Is there anything I should keep in mind when running my new **solid** metal vent pipe to the outside exterior wall through this attic space?
2. Since I'm dealing with insulation, does it have to be protected?
3. Is there a certain clearance from the insulation required?

**PLAN:**
Our current dryer actually vents very close to the floor, so I would like the piping to run as low as possible to avoid lots/any flex tube for a straight shot outside. As you can probably tell from the picture, right now in the laundry room there is about 4' of flex hose connecting the bottom of the dryer to this higher up "vent" hole in the wall right into the attic.

Comment: Free lint insulation. What's the problem? :P

Comment: I am surprised it is not moldy. Vents to the outside have been required for many years not supposed to be vented to attic space or crawl space. If you do go UP make sure to have a clean out at the bottom to clear the lint buildup.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Just that a long vertical can result in more cold air injection--the weight of a column creates more downforce. The same is true in reverse for hot-attic days. Also, as you can plainly see, dryers emit lint. You might consider a soffit vent to keep the lint off your roof.
2. Nope. Pack it snug to the vent pipe.
3. Nope. Fire is not a concern here.

Answer (score 1):

Oh, your own homemade blown-in insulation, every bit helps. Yeah, I totally agree with the gable wall idea. You'd see that it's working & clear. Much easier & safer to install with better waterproofing. And, easier cleanouts requiring just a vacuum & vent end removal...nothing to move nor disconnect inside.

I also agree with running it along the joists. Strong flow because of just one bend & fully supported. You could throw some drywall or cement board scraps under it to abate any fire ideas. But, you're plan is solid.

Answer (score 1):

Everything in the other answers and here's my input.

You might want to thick about insulating the duct.  The hot, moist air will condense on the inside of the duct during the winter and you can end up with water leaking out or mold and rust inside the vent.

They make insulated flexible metal duct that would be an easy run, but I'm not sure how long of a run you're allowed to use it for.

Also consider you'll have to clean this every so often so keep things somewhat accessible.